# Do all functions represent a section of an n dimensional object by another object of n-1 dimension?

Tags: geometry, functions, conic-sections, cross-sections

If $x^2 + y^2 = 4$ represents the section of a cone by a plane horizontal to the cone, a circle, and $y^2 - x^4 = 4$ represents the section of a cone by a plane vertical to the cone, a hyperbola, what do $x^3 + y^3 = 8$ and  $y^3 - x^3 = 8$ represent?  sections of a 4-dimensional version of a cone by a 3-dimensional object?  What about equations like $x^3 + y^2 = 8$?   What does x + y = 2 represent (my first thought was the section of a triangle by a line, but that doesn't seem to make much sense)?  Do these (and by extension all equations) represent a section of one object of n dimension by another object of n-1 dimension?

Hopefully you can answer all of these questions, I put the title as being *Do all equations represent a section of an n dimensional object by another object of n-1 dimension?* because I think it covers all of my questions in a broader way.

Comment: You don’t have any examples of a function representing a section of any of the objects you named. You have _equations_ whose solution sets are those sections. It’s a subtle point, but if you use the right words it’s more likely that any answers will answer the right question.

Comment: @DavidK how would you suggest I improve it?  I don't see what you're saying

Comment: On further consideration this is probably not really confusing anyone, but if you simply changed the word "function" to "equation" each time it appears in the question, it would be a more accurate description, because $x^2+y^2=4$ (for example) is an equation. By the way, all of your equations happen to be polynomial equations, so I wonder if you actually meant to ask only about polynomial equations (which is an interesting field of study) or equations of $n-1$ variables in general (for example, $\sin(x) + y^2 = 8$).

Comment: @DavidK any equation, be it trigonometric, logarithmic, anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get started, let's look at your first example. If you're working in a two-dimensional Cartesian space, the equation $x^2 + y^2 = 4$ is a circle.
Of course in two-dimensional Cartesian space you cannot make a three-dimensional figure at all, since there's no third dimension to extend into.

In three-dimensional Cartesian coordinates the equation $x^2 + y^2 = 4$ describes an infinite cylinder. The $z$ coordinate can be anything (since it was not mentioned in the equation) but the equation restricts $x$ and $y$ so that the point $(x,y,z)$ is exactly $2$ units away from the $z$-axis.

In three dimensions, if you want to describe a circle, you need *two* equations.
One equation can just select a $z$ coordinate.
The simultaneous equations $x^2 + y^2 = 4$ and $z = 2$ select a circle centered on the $z$-axis in a plane parallel to the $x,y$ plane and at a distance $2$ from the $x,y$ plane.
(You can also get a circle without setting $z$ to a constant;
this is merely one way to get a circle.)

The circle given by $x^2 + y^2 = 4$ and $z = 2$ is a section of the cone
$x^2 + y^2 - z^2 = 0,$ consistent with your question.
But it's also (trivially) a section of the cylinder $x^2 + y^2 = 4,$
a section of the sphere $x^2 + y^2 + (z - 2)^2 = 4,$
a section of the sphere $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 8,$
and a section of the hyperboloid $x^2 + y^2 - \frac12 z^2 = 2.$

Somewhat more generally, you can take any plane shape described by two simultaneous equations, a polynomial equation in $x$ and $y$ and an equation setting $z$ to a constant, delete the "$z=\text{constant}$" equation, and you have the equation of a kind of cylinder--not generally a circular cylinder, but these other shapes are generically called cylinders as well.
If the original equations included $z=0,$ you could get a more interesting shape by deleting $z=0$ and inserting some $z$ terms (any positive power of $z$ multiplied by any constant, any non-negative power of $x,$ and any non-negative power of $y$) into the polynomial equation so it is a polynomial equation of $x,$ $y,$ and $z$ that reduces to the original polynomial equation when $z=0.$
If the original equations included $z=c,$ instead of inserting $z$ terms in the equation, insert terms using positive powers of $z - c$ multiplied by any constant, any non-negative power of $x,$ and any non-negative power of $y$.
Then your original plane figure will be a section of the three-dimensional figure described by your new equation.

What will the three-dimensional figure be? It could be any number of shapes. You can easily throw enough polynomial terms into the equation to produce a shape that has never been given a name.
And if you already had an unnamed shape in two dimensions then it almost sure has no name in three.

The same principles apply to $n$ dimensions. Set the last dimension constant and a polynomial equation over the other $n-1$ coordinates describes a figure in $n-1$ dimensions. This could be a section of any one of an infinite (mostly unnamed) $n$-dimensional figures.

If the equations can be general equations over the coordinates then the possibilities open up even more. But that only makes it even harder to categorize the results.

Comment: What specifically does x^3 + y^3 = 8 represent?

Comment: If you translate, rotate, and scale it sufficiently (possibly different scaling in the $x$ and $y$ directions), I think you can make it match some variety of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conchoid_of_de_Sluze. There might be another name for it in the exact form $x^3+y^3=k,$ but I have no idea what that would be. There are some examples of cubic curves at http://www.milefoot.com/math/planecurves/cubics.htm to give you some idea of how weird they can get.